# Read the values from properties file

Tags: java, properties

I have created a dynamic web project in Eclipse and have written a simple code to read from properties file.
Here is my code

```
public class AutocompleteService {

public static void main (String args[])
{
  Properties properties = new Properties(); 
  properties.load(new FileInputStream("autocomplete.properties"));
  System.out.println("Test : " + properties.getProperty("test"));   
}
```

When I run this I got file not found exception.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: autocomplete.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

My package structure is as below

```
-src
 - com.serive (package)
   - AutocompleteService.java
   - autocomplete.properties
```

Both `AutocompleteService.java` and `autocomplete.properties` are in same package i.e. `com.service`.Do we need to anything else to read from properties file ?

Ref: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html

~Ajinkya.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the stream relative to your class:

```
AutocompleteService.class.getResourceAsStream("autocomplete.properties")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked and its less complex than others. :)

Comment: should be `getResourceAsStream` though.

Comment: @Thilo :Yes, it should be.I used `properties.load(AutocompleteService.class.getResourceAsStream("autocomplete.properties"));`

Answer (score 7):

you have to load this from the classpath: ex

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

When you have the stream you can pass it to properties.load()

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looking in the "current directory" when the application is run.

Use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to read from the same place as the classes.

Comment: no, that depends on how you are launching the application, typically it will be your workspace directory when working in Eclipse, you can control this in the Run Configuration, Arguments tab. But then when  you run the application stand-alone, you'll probably have the app in a JAR, so you can't expect the class directory to be current directory. Use getResourceAsStream() and you work inside Eclipse and stand-alone.

Answer (score 2):

The "current" directory is where you started the server from, so refer to your file relative to that, eg `"config/autocomplete.properties"` or wherever you like.

The best approach is to *know* what the problem is. Use code like this that helps you debug the problem:

```
File propertiesFile = new File("config/autocomplete.properties");
if (!propertiesFile.exists())
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find properties file: " + propertiesFile.getAbsolutePath());
properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
```

If this explodes, the exception message will show you where it thinks the file is, and yo'll quickly figure out how to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an input stream using a relative path will try to open a file in the current directory of the running program. In your case, the current directory is the directory of execution of your servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.)

What you want to do is to open a properties file which is located along with your classes, in the war file. This properties file should thus be laoded by the class loader, and using [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) is the appropriate way. Look at the linked javadoc to understand which kind of path to supply as argument.